# Need help about below code how to display in pages?

Tags: php

How to display it in pages?

I want to show result in pages. Anyone know how then please help me. so it can be navigate easily. :)

code by RakeshS

```
example : ?page=1 ?page=2

    $images = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
     <?php
    $imgTot = count($images);

    echo '<div>';

    for($i=0; $i<$imgTot; $i++)
    {
        if ($i % 10 == 0) {
            echo '<div>';
        }

        echo '<img alt="'.$image->alttext.'" src="'.$image->thumbnailURL.'" />';

        if ($i % 10 == 9) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';

    ?>
```

Comment: where does $images come from?

Comment: Its get image from array.

Comment: from where $images array and $image object is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to iterate through images array, then try it in this way,

```
<?php
    $page = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
       $page = intval($_GET['page']); 
       $pageLimit = $page * 10;
       $page = $pageLimit - 9; 
    }

    if($page > 0){
       echo '<div>';
       for($i=$page; $i<$pageLimit; $i++)
       {
          echo '<div>';
          echo '<img alt="'.$images[$i]['alttext'].'" src="'.$images[$i]['thumbnailURL'].'" />';
          echo '</div>';
       }
       echo '</div>';
    }

  ?>
```

if you are trying to iterate $image object it is not defined.

Comment: thanks for reply. please can u tell me how to archive ?page

Comment: you mean achieve page! just add $page = $_GET['page];

Comment: add ?page in url and show result.

Comment: I have done edit on answer is this is something you want please vote it as best answer, you can add comment incase you want to know anything else.

Comment: $page contains the url parameter if you want to test it just echo it.

Comment: i need ?page=2 so its show next 11-20 image not all images.

Comment: Edited the solution please mark it best solution and upvote it, if it has resolved your issue.

Comment: I hope $images[1]['alttext'] is set in your array.

Comment: sorry i can't upvote u. Its need 15 rep but i've less then.

Comment: No Problem, Thanks for appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

$image is not define.
you can add a line code

    `$image = $images[$i];`

```
echo '<img alt="'.$image->alttext.'" src="'.$image->thumbnailURL.'" />';
```

i hope it help to you!